# How could option vega be remapped on reduced volatility surface?

Tags: volatility-smile, vega

try to be clear to ask my question:
Suppose the original vol surface is a n by m matrix where n is the number of pillars in the volatility term structure and m is the number of strikes. According to my portfolio of options with different strikes and maturities, suppose my vega is distributed along the original n by m matrix.

Suppose then I somehow have to remap vega a reduced volatility surface with just 3 of original strikes, how shoud I take into account the vega associated with the remaining n-3 strikes in the original vol surface?

Thanks a lot!

V.

Comment: What I have seen in practice is a linear attribution to the new buckets. In a one-dimensional case, you put all exposure below the first pillar onto the first pillar, all exposure after the last pillar on the last pillar, and linearly balance all exposures in between the pillars. In a matrix case, this would mean bi-linear reattribution. Would such an approach be applicable in your case?

Comment: Hi! What you suggest is exactly what a colleague of mine used to do. For very practical reasons, we need to cluster vega in buckets along the strike dimension only. This is required to estimate how the value of our portfolio of options reacts under peculiar volatility bumps to specific strikes. Another methodology (very practical) I am exploiting is to somwehow interpolate these volatility bumps on neighboring strikes

Comment: I think you could have some luck with the **bucketing** sections in one of those market risk books from Carol Alexander. What you are suggesting sounds like the method of attributing 'bumps' to the nodes. Sorry, I have no concrete resource (or answer, for that matter) at hand.

Comment: Hi! I know Carol Alexander, I will have a look at one of her books :) Thank you very much